# making a tic tac toe game in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tic-tac-toe

Im making a tic tac toe in js for learning purposes however I am a little stuck. my code is:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('td');
    tableR.item(i).appendChild(newElement);
    newElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (elementIsEmpty(newElement)) {
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            if (xTurn) {
                img.src = 'images/x.svg';
                x.push(String(i) + String(j))
            }
            else {
                img.src = 'images/o.png';
                o.push(String(i) + String(j))
            }
            newElement.append(img)
            console.log("here")
            checkWinOrDraw(xTurn)
            xTurn = !xTurn
        }

    })

}
```

}

and my checkWinOrDraw function is:

```
 let winPat = [['00', '10', '20'], ['01', '11', '21'], ['02', '12', '22'], ['00', '01', '02'], ['10', '11', '12'], ['20', '21', '22'], ['00', '11', '22'], ['02', '11', '20']];
function checkWinOrDraw(xTurn) {
for (let i = 0; i < winPat.length; i++) {
    if (xTurn) {

        if (winPat[i].every(element => x.includes(element))) {
            
            alert('X wins')
            reset()
            return
        }

    }
    else {

        if (winPat[i].every(element => o.includes(element))) {
            alert('O wins')
            reset()
            return
        }

    }
}


for (let item of td) {
    if (elementIsEmpty(item))
        return
}
alert('Draw')
reset()
```

}

However, when the game ends, the last image is not shown on the screen. For example, when X wins, I get an alert("x wins") but the image of x in the cell is not rendered.

Comment: Probably not a legitimate fix and more of a hack but you could a timeout before the alert. I did this in a hangman game I made when I ran into the same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using JS to make tic tac toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69604874/using-js-to-make-tic-tac-toe)